# Building an app in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I am just starting to code by myself in Flutter. I've built this so far and here is the image. Can you show me what would be better or cleaner code? I used Row widget for it, but I guess I should maybe go with the Stack. Because now I want to add a text field box in the middle of the app bar that overflows in the down direction.

[image]

```
child: Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(255, 202, 6, 1),
        appBar: PreferredSize(
          preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(90.0),
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, top: 20, bottom: 10),
            child: Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                CircleAvatar(backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                      "https://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/w_200,h_200,c_thumb,g_face,r_max/face_left.png"),
                  radius: 32,
                  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                  child: AppBar(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                    elevation: 0,
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 13, top: 8),
                  child: Text(
                    'Someones Name',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 100, bottom: 30),
                  child: Switch(
                    inactiveThumbColor: Colors.white,
                    activeColor: Colors.grey[700],
                    value: false,
                    onChanged: (bool state) {
                      print(state);
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        body: Container(
          height: 800,
          width: 500,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Color.fromRGBO(251, 251, 251, 1),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
              top: Radius.circular(15),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
    overflow: Overflow.visible,
  ),
);
```

And this is look I want to achieve:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Code Review!  The current question title states your concerns about the code and asks a question. The site standard is for the title to simply *state the task* accomplished by the code. Please see [ask] for examples, and revise the title accordingly.